# About the growing path of every mechanism on the psychology defense system

Tags: test, freud

About the growing path of every mechanism on the psychology defense systemI Have seen [the below video which](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhG-twzaE_g) is about the Freud’s 5 Stages of Psychosexual Development:

[image]

Also i  have seen [the psychology defense mechanisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defence_mechanism), and i guess **those defense mechanisms** have [fuzzy rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_rule) and have **high relationship to each other**, especially to **their neighborhood mechanisms** on their defense level!.

So, i try to **online** track my defense system, and detect being on every one of 4 defense level by **at moment** **measuring** the **correlation** of every detected mechanism by the other Mechanism on the level of that mechanism.

But if i have **some growing pattern map** for the psychology defense **mechanism**, it could help to better online tracking and detecting and up or downing the mechanism levels.

So, I guess at **the academic papers** or the internet **posts**, there must exist some growing pattern like shown below:

[image]

If possible, i like to know how could find that path of growing every psychology defense mechanism, and find some growing pattern like said on above video for every defense mechanism as a growing Child pattern?

[image]

And finally if the above mechanism are made from [unconscious mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscious_mind), and are hard to be detected and **the above classification** is so hard to be done!, I like to find some search **tag** for finding **the new methods** to track those mechanisms by running some experiments or seeing **the computer simulation results** on this field which could be done based of the new technologies like [freud robots](http://future-nonstop.org/c/1132e34caea2e498005ada2c2e57bf56) or ...!

Thanks.

Comment: Freud is pretty much entirely pseudoscience. You can study what the guy thought about things as a matter of history and appreciation for his contributions to modern thinking about psychology, but if you try to use Freudian theories to actually understand the real world you're going to be quite disappointed.

Comment: As @BryanKrause will be aware, although this question covers areas of psychology [considered by some here to be pseudoscientific](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2242), Freud is very much alive in psychology and [I am very much a defender of Freudian and Neo-Freudian psychology](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2248)

Comment: I will try and come up with an answer, but in the meantime, there is a question relating to Freud's Psychosocial Development Theory which I answered at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/17037/7604